# Select next sibling based on grandchild value with pure css

Tags: html, css

I have to set span tag with "Some Text" InnerHTML to red color whenever previous input tag is having a zero value. Ex: In following sample HTML code first "Some Text" span tag should be in red color.

```
<td data-colid="some id1" >
    <div>
        <div>
            <span data-varname="somename">$0.00</span>
            <input value="$0.0"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <span>Some Text</span>
</td>
<td data-colid="some id2" >
        <div>
            <div>
                <span data-varname="somename">$10.00</span>
                <input value="$10.0"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
<td>
    <span>Some Text</span>
</td>
```

These are the only id(s) available for working, no additional classes or java script are available.Please Help me with some pointers.

Comment: CSS selectors can at present select only children, descendants (or) sibling (coming after the current element in the DOM). `input` and `span` with "some text" doesn't have any of those relation.

Comment: CSS: not possible. JavaScript: possible. HTML: possible

Comment: @Harry: Thanks for your response, Is there any other work-around with some complicated selector chain?

Comment: @Sudarshan: With CSS it is only possible if you can change your HTML to satisfy one of those relations. If not, JS as CodeiSir has mentioned.

Comment: @CodeiSir: Thanks for your response. Could you please provide me some references or pointers on how it can be accomplished using javascript?

Comment: @Sudarshan well how do you know about JavaScipt? use `oninput` for the input in order to check if its 0. Use DOM-Traversing to change to CSS for the SPAN

Comment: If you are looking for an implementation using JS, then [here is a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/6wcwbv8c/2/). Note: I am assuming the data-colid will be different for each `tr`.

Comment: @Harry: Thanks for your answer and efforts, unfortunately product management will not accept any js solutions at this moment. but thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

try this using jquery:

with "Some Text" as condition

```
$('td span:contains("Some Text")').css('color','black');
$('td input[value="$0.0"]').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('span:contains("Some Text")').css('color','red');
})
```

without text condition

```
$('td input').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('span').css('color','black');
})
$('td input[value="$0.0"]').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('span').css('color','red');
})
```

Comment: and nothing happens when the value changes?

Comment: but how? and it should not only get red, but also reverse back when the values changes

Comment: use this    $('td span:contains("Some Text")').css('color','black') inside onchange before excuting the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use your code because it's a headache trying to keep track of so many divs. This is a simple HTML layout and a complex CSS, and no JS/jQ. If you change your layout like my demo, not only will it work great, it'll be readable, and semantic as well. ;-)

This is a custom checkbox, that I've made into a semi-permanent marker to flag the condition you required (i.e. $0.0 = red text). This is a rare example of CSS actually doing something that was done only with script in the past. If you require it to be programmatically controlled, let me know and I'll put some JS in.

Btw, I know *"production"* is frightened by by new technologies like HTML and JS, so you don't have to reiterate. CodeSir and Harry are correct in that you or *"production"* must be more flexible and join the 21<sup>st</sup> century and use HTML and JS.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>34923541</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #222;
      color: #eee;
      font: 400 16px/1.4'Verdana';
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    fieldset {
      margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
      padding: 8px;
      border-radius: 9px;
      border: 3px double #FF8;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 19em;
    }
    legend {
      font: small-caps 700 1.5rem/2"Palatino Linotype";
      color: #FD1;
    }
    /* Demo #1 */
    input.fade {
      display: none;
    }
    input.fade + label {
      color: #DDD;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    input.fade + label span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #555;
      line-height: 100%;
    }
    input.fade:checked + label span:after {
      content: 'X';
      color: #F00;
      font-family: cursive;
      font-style: oblique;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    input.fade + label span:after {
      content: '';
      color: #F00;
      font-family: cursive;
      font-style: oblique;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    input.fade + label + output:before {
      content: '$10.00';
      color: #Fc0;
      font-family: 'Raleway';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    input.fade:checked + label + output:before {
      content: '$0.00';
      color: red;
      font-family: cursive;
      font-style: oblique;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    input.fade + label + output:after {
      content: 'Available';
      color: #Fc0;
      font-family: `Raleway`;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    input.fade:checked + label + output:after {
      content: 'Sold Out';
      color: red;
      font-family: cursive;
      font-style: oblique;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    input.fade + label span,
    input.fade:checked + label span {
      -webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear;
      -moz-transition: background 0.4s linear;
      transition: background 0.4s linear;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Demo #1</legend>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk1' id="chk1" class="fade" value='2' />
    <label for="chk1"><span></span> 
    </label>
    <output id="out1" for="chk1"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </output>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .... Unfortunately, HTML structure is rigid and cannot be modified(All Div tags should be preserved, even though redundant) .. It seems like a dead end for pure css solution ..

Comment: Indeed it does, have you looked into SCSS, SASS, or LESS? I'm not sure but that might help.